# Can't bind to 'active' since it isn't a known property of 'mat-tab'

Tags: angular

I'm having this error even if I imported `MatTabsModule`.

here's how my component looks like:

```
@Component({
selector: 'app-settings-page',
template: `
<mat-tab-group animationDuration="0ms">
  <mat-tab
    *ngFor="let routeLink of routeLinks; let i = index;"
    [label]="routeLink.label"
    [routerLink]="routeLink.link"
    [active]="activeLinkIndex === i">
  </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>`
})
```

Comment: post how you have imported MatTabModule

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As i see the problem here is using `<mat-tab-group>`, remove that part and it should work fine.

```
  <mat-tab
    *ngFor="let routeLink of routeLinks; let i = index;"
    [label]="routeLink.label"
    [routerLink]="routeLink.link"
    [active]="activeLinkIndex === i">
  </mat-tab>
```